# Symfony: save null instead of empty string

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

I have a table and one of the columns can be null.

In symfony, with generated form, when i leave field for that column empty, script saves to database an empty string instead of null.

How to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override your doSave() function in your form after you check and set your form value to do whatever you want.

```
  protected function doSave($con = null) {

    if ($this->getValue('myFormValue') == '') {  // do whatever test you want to determine if the variable should be null
        $this->setMyFormValue(null);  // if it is, set it null
        } 
    parent::doSave($con);  // continue with the parent save()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 4 you can define in your form field

```php
$formBuilder->add('field_name', TextType::class, [
  'required' => false, // optional
  'empty_data' => '', // it mean if null -> set ''
])
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could do something like this:
`if (empty($var)) $var = null;`